# Detect waves in the signal real-time

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a signal with waves like gaussians or half gaussians. What I want to is to calculate real time when an wave peak is happening and the length of the wave. For example I have got the following signal:

[image]

I want to detect the 5 main wave peaks of the signal. Their max values, their duration and their values. How can I locate them real time? My signal is stored in a C# queue. What should I perform in order to detect the waves real time?

```
if (currentValue >threshold1 && (currentValue - previousValue) > 0)
{
       firstCondition = true; 
}
if (currentValue > threshold2  && currentValue < threshold2  && (currentValue - previousValue) > 0 && firstCondition == true)
{
       secondCondition = true;
}
if (currentValue > (threshold2-0.02)   && (currentValue ) < threshold2 && (currentValue - previousValue) < 0 && firstCondition == true && secondCondition == true)
{
       thirdCondition = true;
       secondCondition = false;
}
if (currentValue > threshold1 && currentValue <threshold1 && (currentValue - previousValue) < 0 && thirdCondition == true)
{
      fourthCondition = true;
      firstCondition = false;
      secondCondition = false;
      thirdCondition = false;
      counter++;
}
```

My code is seemed that is performing a basic detection. However it seems that I am loosing some waves. I am guessing that is based on the thresholds. My second question is how can I keep the timestamps which correlated from the beginning and the end of the wave?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for an algorithm

Comment: you could use smoothing to simplify the search (box-smoothing would be the simplest). Afterwards things should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: What I did in first step was to cross-correlate the signal with a reference wave. Thus I got as a signal the cross-correlation output which is a smooth signal. However, after the smoothing of the signal I have to implement some heuristics in order to get my desired waves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proces sample by sample. If sample > min-threshold-1, it's propably a wave begininig. Then you start counter. Each new sample above min-threshold-2 (which is a bit lower than min-threshold-1) increments counter. If counter > min-wave-length, then you got a wave. But you still processing. If sample < min-threshold-2, then it wave end. Then repeat it again and again.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. For example min_threshold-1 could be 0.4 (why min-threshold-2 is lower that min-1?) and my signal take values from 0-1. Can you give me simple example of your solution?

Comment: Ok that imply that my signal has to pass from the first threshold and to begin to counter, after that to pass from the second threshold. If the wave length of the counter is bigger than a third threshold I got a window. Am I right? How can I do that thing real time. Do I have to create flags in order to check if those conditions are met?

Comment: And also in order to check both thresholds I have to have nested if statements in order to check in the same time  if those condition are fulfilled?

Comment: In real time, for example you create a Thread which can read samples. It will execute in infinite loop GetMextSample(). If there is no new sample, it just waits. If new sample is arrived, it checks is this sample above or under threshold etc. This thread should have state, it should know it is inside wave or not. If it is inside wave and new sample is under threshold so we have new wave, it can raise an event NewWaveFound. Cant give you code sample because I am at work now, little busy.

Comment: My signal is updated real time. Since I am not familiar with threads and event based coding in c#, what I did was just to add 4 if statements with the desired conditions and 4 flags which I passed from one if to another in order to check that if statements happen in specific order. (I appreciate your help (especially since you are on work).